# Lie groups with no free $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ action

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

What is  an example of  a  Lie group which does not have  a fixed point- free  homeomorphism of order 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group $\mathbb{R}$ works. To see that, note that any homeomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ of order two must be decreasing, so its graph intersects the line $y = x$, so $f$ has a fixed point.

As pointed out by John Ma in the comments, we cannot take the Lie group to be compact, since any compact Lie group contains a non-trivial torus, and therefore an element of order two. Multiplication by that element then gives a homeomorphism of order two.

Comment: Thanks for saving me that last minute of typing (+1). Discarding 3 lines is fine :-)

Comment: Just curious, is there any compact example?

Comment: @John Ma I'm not sure, but perhaps something like $\textrm{SO}(3)$ works? I would have to think a bit about this.

Comment: $SO(3)$ is $\mathbb S^3 /\{\pm 1\}$, so it's a double cover of a Lens space $\mathbb S^3/\mathbb Z_4$ so it seems that it has such a homeomorphism (I do not know the answer too).

Comment: @MarcPaul  $SO(3)$  does  not work

Comment: @JohnMa $SO(3)$ has  an element of order 2 so there is  a free action by $Z/2Z$

Comment: My reason that I did not restrict myself to compact groups was that: I was starting with $R^2$ rather $R$. There is  a free action of $Z/2Z$ on the plane.

Comment: I think then there is a free $\mathbb Z_2$ action on all compact Lie groups, as there are order $2$ elements in each compact Lie group, as suggested by @AliTaghavi

Comment: @JohnMa why is there an order 2 element?

Comment: Every compact Lie groups must have a toric subgroup $\mathbb S^1$, that $-1$ in $\mathbb S^1$ will be an order two element. @AliTaghavi

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks. Are there some other Lie group which do not admit a free Z_{2} action(other than R)?

Comment: Ah yes you are right, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Can you describ that free action on $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @JohnMa  The plane is diffeomorphic to the Poincare upper plane which is  a Lie group with an order two element. The upper plane is identified with all linear maps on R in the form $at+b$ where $a$ is positive.The group operation is "composition). Then $1-t$ is  an order 2 element.

Comment: @AliTaghavi But $1-t$ is not of the form $at +b$ with $a$ positive, right?

Comment: @MarcPaul Yes.I am sorry.

Comment: @JohnMa  as you see the action which I mentioned was incorrect. Do you think that the existence of such free action on the plane is an obvious question?