# Free $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ action on the plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-actions, fixed-point-theorems

Motivated by the following question we ask:

> Is there a free action of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ by homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

[Lie groups with no free $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499740/lie-groups-with-no-free-mathbbz-2-mathbbz-action)

Comment: No, if we denote the qoutient by $Q$, the $1=\chi(\mathbb{R}^2)=\chi(Q)\chi(\mathbb{Z}/(2))=2\chi(Q)$, which is impossible.

Comment: @PaxKivimae Why not write up your comment as a short answer, since it essentially resolves the question?

Comment: @Travis I have a bad habit of writing comments instead of answering...

Comment: @PaxKivimae I'm trying to shake the habit myself. (+1, b.t.w.)

Comment: Any free action by a finite group is automatically properly discontinuous, and hence the quotient map is a covering map. In particular the quotient would be a non-compact surface with fundamental group $\Bbb Z/2$. However, no such surface exists.

Comment: @PVAL thank you for interesting comment. Can I ask you to write it as an answer? After your comment and based on it I found the following MO post: On the other hand the quotient surface is just a topological surface (not necessarily orientable) How can we resolve this (possible) problem?I hope that you add an answer not a comment.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/fundamental-groups-of-noncompact-surfaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have an integer invariant of topological spaces, called the [euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition). This has two special properties, namely that for a covering map $X\to Y$, with fiber $F$, we have $\chi(X)=\chi(Y)|F|$. In this case, if the action is free, the map $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2/\{gx=x\}=Q$ is a covering map with fiber $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, so that we have that $\chi(\mathbb{R}^2)=2\chi(Q)$, so that $\chi(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is even. But you can easily compute that $\chi(\mathbb{R}^2)=1$, so we have our contridiction!

Comment: Is not necessary to have "FINITE CW complex"? Moreover are we sure tha the quotient space is  a finite CW complex?Is not necessary that the action would be cellular?

Comment: Working with CW complexes is entirely unnecessary. You can use singular homology, for example $$\chi(X) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \beta_i$$ where $\beta_i$ is the rank of of the singular homology group $H_i(X;\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @LeeMosher  Thank you for your comment. Does the formula of Euler characteristic of total space of fibre bundle or covering space works for non CW  complex? Where is  a  proof of this fact?

Comment: @Ali this is discussed in the second paragraph of the linked page.

Comment: @PaxKivimae I think that there is  a  misunderstanding?I was aware of this alternative definition of $\chi$. But my question is that : Is the product formula you mentioned in your answer, valid without assumption finite CW complex?Where is  a proof?

Comment: @Ali yeap, the fact is a simple corrolarry of the Kunneth theorem, which should be proved in the first few chapters of any book on algebraic topology! I would really dissuade you from thinking of this as a finite CW complex thing, this really is an invariant of topological spaces, and everything in that article is true in general, this really is a general invariant, that just happens to be easy to calculate in one case.